# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content. laravel project

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I was installing the package when I suddenly received this error.
My laravel project version is 8.83.23 . 
This was the command I entered in the terminal.

```bash
composer require vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq
```

I even entered the command with the library version, but it still gives the same error.
So I searched the overflow stack but the problem still exists.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: The error is pretty obvious, did you read it? It is saying you are using `PHP 8.0` but the package required `PHP 7.3 or 7.4`...

Comment: Before changing the version to 8.0, I tested it on version 7.3, but it was still the same error

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Keep the php version to 8 or above.

Then, I would delete the `composer.lock` and run `composer update`. Usually, the version conflicts can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors/issues in the image:

- Your PHP version is `8.0` and it is asking for `7.3` or `7.4` (that is `Problem 2`)
- `Problem 1` is saying that `jenssegers/mongodb` requires the version to be `^3.9` (`3.9.0 <= version > 4.0.0`), but the package is hardcoded to be `3.8.5` on your `composer.json`. So, you need to share you composer json, but if you have something like this:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "3.8.5"
    }
}
```

You will needed to change it to this:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.8.5"
    }
}
```

---

But please, share your `composer.json`

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, I finally found the problem. The reason for this problem is simply that the requirements of the package we want to install do not match the requirements of Laravel.

Thank you for your suggestions.